# alternative to fitColumns() in Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to dynamically fit columns in the grid.
Is there anything in Ext JS 4 which resizes each column to fit the grid like method fitColumns() in Ext JS 3.4?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one of grid columns has `flex:1` then the columns are resized to fit the grid width.

Comment: i want to make something like this, but i recieve an error: handler :  function(){
       
        for (var i = 0; i < this.grid.columns.length; i++) {
            this.grid.columns[i].flex=1;
            }

    }

Comment: Not like that. Add `flex:1` to the column configuration of the column you want to stretch. You can add flex also to other columns to set their relative widths. For example:     columns:[
         {dataIndex:'firstName', text:'First Name'}
        ,{dataIndex:'lastName', text:'Last Name', **flex:1**}
    ]

Comment: thanks, Saki, but the problem is it should be done dynamically, for example, after clicking a button

Comment: Haven't done it but you can try to change widths/flexes of columns and then call `grid.getView().refresh()`, no warranty though.

Comment: it is working!!! handler : function(){ for (var i = 0; i < this.grid.columns.length; i++) { this.grid.columns[i].flex=1; this.grid.getView().refresh()} } Thanks a lot! have a nice day, Saki